# Objective-C: Height of CGRect?

Tags: objective-c

I want to get the height of a CGRect-rectangle. I have a simple problem in understanding why these lines return 0 height:

```
    CGRect lalaframe = CGRectMake(10, 30, 45, 50);
    NSLog(@"_height of test frame = %d",lalaframe.size.height);
```

Should be an easy fix...
Thanks!

Answer (score 7):

You're logging with `%d`, that formats an integer. Try using `%f` (for float) instead.

Answer (score 1):

agree with cobbal.  I use

```
NSLog(@"frame :%@", NSStringFromCGRect(lalaframe))
```

most of the time because of its simplicity.

Answer (score 0):

use:

```
NSLog("_height of test frame: %f", lalaframe.size.height);
```

It will log the height of the frame.

%d is for decimal numbers (int, <strike>long, short</strike>)
%f is for floating numbers (<strike>float</strike>, double)